# How to Put condition in Mongodb if condition is exists?

Tags: mongodb

I need a help, How can I conditionally put object query in $and array? Like if user doesnt supply man value then `{ deliveryman:  man }` filter will be removed.

```
 let products = await Product.find({
        $and: [
          {
            $and: [
              { deliveryman:  man },
              { marchent: marchent },
              { productStatus: status },
              { hub: branch },
            ],
          },

          {
            $or: [{ createdAt: { $gt: date1 } }, { createdAt: { $lt: date2 } }],
          },
        ],
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable that is an array which you can conditionally push objects and use that variablein your query. For example,

```
const query = []

if (typeof man !== 'undefined') {
    query.push({ deliveryman: man })
}

if (typeof marchent !== 'undefined') {
    query.push({ marchent })
}

if (typeof status !== 'undefined') {
    query.push({ productStatus: status })
}

if (typeof branch !== 'undefined') {
    query.push({ hub: branch })
}

let products = await Product.find({
    $and: [
        { $and: query },
        { $or: [
            { createdAt: { $gt: date1 } }, 
            { createdAt: { $lt: date2 } }
        ] },
    ],
})
```

---

For an [implicit AND operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/), MongoDB provides one when specifying a comma separated list of expressions thus the above can also be represented as:

```
const query = {}

if (typeof man !== 'undefined') {
    query.deliveryman = man 
}

if (typeof marchent !== 'undefined') {
    query.marchent = marchent
}

if (typeof status !== 'undefined') {
    query.productStatus = status
}

if (typeof branch !== 'undefined') {
    query.hub = branch
}

let products = await Product.find({
    $and: [
        query,
        { $or: [
            { createdAt: { $gt: date1 } }, 
            { createdAt: { $lt: date2 } }
        ] },
    ],
})
```